# Most Effective Method to create and fill a numpy matrix from an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

So I have this array, lets call this array `arr= ["a", "b", "c"]`
(my array is about 6200 elements long) and I want to be able to create a numpy matrix, by "squaring" this array and filling it with a custom function. 
So we would end up with the following

```
    "a",     "b",    "c"
"a" f(a,a)  f(a,b)  f(c,c)
"b" f(b,a)  f(b,b)  f(b,c)
"c" f(c,a)  f(c,b)  f(c,c)
```

stored as a numpy array. However, my custom function returns the same value for f(a,b) and f(b,a), so I was wondering if there was a method that would allow me to only compute half the matrix along the diagonal effectively and filling the rest. Ideally there would also be a way to parallelize this solution allowing me to run it on a hpc much faster.

If manually doing it is the most effective way with two for loops and with the interior cutting off when it hits the diaganal then please let me know, I was just wondering if there was a faster way.

Comment: Can you provide the function? There might be a fast way if the function is vectorizable.  In regards to your last point it should be simple to only compute the upper diagonal and then reflect across the lower if the function is indeed transitive.

Comment: If it cannot be vectorized particularly well, then perhaps take a note from how [`pandas` creates the correlation matrix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L7495-L7515). That simple loop structure should suffice

Comment: @user3483203 lets say the function is something along the lines of a distance function. I am not working with strings directly and the function is not vectorizable

Comment: @ALollz thank you, however the pandas correlation matrix is done manually as I thought it would have to be done. I was wondering if there is a faster way(ie like a numpy method or something of that sort.)

Comment: By looping `for i in range(N): for j in range(i,N):` you can assign `f[i,j]` and `f[j,i]` in the same iteration.  But compared to looping `j` for the whole `N`, you'll get at best a 2x speedup.  But if the function could calculate values for a whole range of `i` and/or `j` in fast compiled code, you could achieve a 10x or better speedup.  Trying to take advantage of the symmetry might even slow such a calculation down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with np.tril_indices and fancy indexing

```
# compute indices of elements in lower triangle
rows,cols=np.tril_indices(arr.shape[0])
# compute arr values for those indices
left,right=arr[rows],arr[cols]
# do the stuff
values=f(left,right)
# preallocate result
res=np.empty((arr.shape[0],arr.shape[0]), dtype=values.dtype)
# assign lower triangle
res[rows,cols]=values
# assing upper triangle
res[cols,rows]=values
```